# How to show ASCII value on the view page in Rails 4?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails 4 + Ruby 2.0

view.html.erb

```
    content =  "<p>Bangalore or Bengaluru &hellip; as you hear of the name you may think only about IT. No &hellip; you have mistaken and this is where you are wrong! ... In fact this capital city of the South Indian state of Karnataka is one of the most sought out tourist destinations in India. Bangalore, though for years is popularly known as &quot;Garden City&quot;, has slowly evolved into &quot;Silicon Valley of India&quot;, and the transformation has been amazing in every aspect. Bengaluru, which got its name from the Kannada (Karnataka&#39;s official language) words &lsquo;benda kaluru&rsquo; meaning &ldquo;land of boiled beans&rdquo;, is not just about globally reputed IT firms, but has plenty to offer in terms of tourism.</p>\r\n\r\n<p>The city boasts with a wide array of attractions for the tourists that include ever green and ecstatic parks, adorable botanical gardens, world famous historical / public monuments, lively lakes, ever alive wildlife sanctuaries, ancient and divine temples, mind-boggling amusement parks, well maintained museums / art galleries, swanky and ever bustling malls, booming IT parks (boasting the highest concentration of IT companies in the country) and what not! Bangalore is also a noted center of renowned academic institutions, scientific and research institutes / organizations besides being a hub of diverse art and cultural activities.<br />\r\n<br />\r\nThere are numerous luxury suites and well maintained lodgings / hotels across the city and of course for all budgets. In addition to the above, you will also find a number of service apartments located at various places.</p>\r\n"
    <% description = sanitize "#{content}", :tags => %w(br a) %>
    <%= raw truncate description, :length => 100 %>
```

in content instance html data is coming that i need to show on the view page/on template
i am using sanitize too but some tages are coming like `&hellip;, &rdquo;, &ldquo;, &#39;` only

it should change into html and it should come like this …, ”, “, ' resp ..

i want to truncate the content without loosing these html tags.

any solution please share...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
<%= raw content %>
```

Which won't escape things to HTML entities. However, in an ideal world you'd construct all your HTML in the view, rather than having it all held in a string variable.

Comment: I think the OP actually wants the html-entities to be escaped and it's not doing it...

Comment: i see this truncate method is having some problem, if i will remove this truncate and length its coming fine...... but i want truncate too with length 100.

Comment: Do you want to truncate the content, and preserve the surrounding HTML tags? It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: yes @sam i want to truncate the content without loosing these html tags.